# .svg image is not loaded into webview in android

Tags: leaflet, android

I'm using leaflet and trying to load .svg image on webview.

```
   `//Create the bounds and image to add.
    var imageUrl = mapData.plan.image;
    var imageBounds = [[mapData.plan.size_x, 0], [0, mapData.plan.size_y]];

    //Add the image overlay to the map
    overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds,{interactive: true});
    overlay.addTo(map);`
```

The image is not loading